# Javacard UICC ADF EF size

Tags: javacard, uicc

I would like to determine the size of an Elemantary File (EF) in a USIM applet ADF file system. TS 102.241 uicc.access.FileView select / status methods return FCP (File Control Parameter) which should hold among others the file size.
From the description in TS 102.221 I'm not sure

1. How can I determine the required size for the fcp buffer in the first place?
2. How can I get the file size tag data from fcp? I don't see any convenient APIs for it?

Thanks!